# Finding mean, variance, and pmf for independent Poisson distributions with different rate parameters

Tags: statistics, poisson-process

In a good year, an organism births $\lambda_1$ offspring per month. In a bad year, the organism births $\lambda_2$ offspring. Of course, $\lambda_1 > \lambda_2$. If we suppose each year was equally and independently like to be a good or bad year, how do we approach:

i) Computing the mean and variance of a randomly selected year?

ii) Computing the conditional pmf of the offspring in a year if given the info that $n$ offspring have been born that year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X$ is the number of offsprings

$E[X]=E[X|\text{good year}]P(\text{good year})+E[X|\text{bad year}]P(\text{bad year})=\frac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{2}$

$E[X^2]=E[X^2|\text{good year}]P(\text{good year})+E[X^2|\text{bad year}]P(\text{bad year})=\frac{\lambda_1^2+\lambda_1+\lambda_2^2+\lambda_2}{2}$

$Var(X)=E[X^2]-E[X]^2=...$

For the second part I assume the question asks for the pmf of a year being a good year/bad year (otherwise it is trivial). Using Bayes formula

$P(\text{good year}|X=n)=\frac{P(X=n|\text{good year})P(\text{good year})}{P(X=n)}=\frac{P(X=n|\text{good year})P(\text{good year})}{P(X=n|\text{good year})P(\text{good year})+P(X=n|\text{bad year})P(\text{bad year})}=...$

Comment: Thank you, @Momo. The question actually asks about computing the conditional pmf of the total numbers of offspring in a good year. That is $P(X = n | \textrm{good year}) = ...$ right?

Comment: Then it should be just the pmf of the Poisson($\lambda_1$)